# Matching everything until a series of characters, without the series itself?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract a portion of text from a string. I need to grab everything before the characters `" (test)"` *first* appear (Note the whitespace before the first parentheses), but excluding the `" (test)"` portion itself.

The string I'm testing this on:

```
"14 asdasddasddasdas twetwe .e.wrwe r342#¤¤¤¤ 822 (test) (test) (test)"
```

I'm using the pattern `^.+(?= \(test\))`, but apparently this matches everything until the *last* `" (test)"` occurrence. I would like it to match the string:

```
 "14 asdasddasddasdas twetwe .e.wrwe r342#¤¤¤¤ 822 "
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` symbol means "one or more times — and preferably as many times as possible". (It's "greedy".) You need to use the special "nongreedy" or "lazy" equivalent, `+?`, which means "one or more times — and preferably as *few* times as possible". (Note: this is not to be confused with the use of `?` to mean "zero or one times — and better one time than zero".) So, your pattern would be:

```
^.+?(?= \(test\))
```